# WebSocket not connecting to socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using Node.js with socket.io to implement websockets in one of my pages. server.js (what Node.js runs) has this code:

```
var http = require("http").createServer(),
io = require("socket.io").listen(http);

http.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
        socket.emit("message", {hello:"world"});
});
```

And this is the code I'm trying to connect with:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://92.60.122.235:8080/");
socket.onopen = function() {  
    alert("Socket has been opened!");  
}
```

When I load the page, nothing happens. I'm using Chrome, and I know websockets are supported. No errors are present in the error console, and if I watch socket.io serving requests from command line I don't see any user connecting.

As far as I know this should work, could anyone explain what could be going wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using socket.io client? I believe they have some authentication, so this is not supposed to work.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware I needed to use the client aswell. I'll try and get back to you.

Comment: Alright, added the socket.io in a script tag above all my other scripts, and it still doesn't work. Same problem as before. I have checked if the server is actually serving the socket.io client script and it is.

Comment: Well you don't use web sockets directly. See my answer. You use io.connect(...) to connect to the server, socket.on(...) to add a listener, and socket.emit(...) to send something. Socket.on doesn't add on the native objects! It has its own!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a socket.io client to pass some authentication phases I believe. Try this, and it should work(the client javascript is served by socket.io itself, don't worry about it).

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('helloworld', { msg: 'why do you so love to say hello world?' });
  });
</script>
```

From http://socket.io/#faq

> **Why not just call it `WebSocket` if the actual WebSocket is not
> present and mimick its API?**
>
> Socket.IO does more than WebSocket, even
> if WebSocket is selected as the transport and the user is browsing
> your website with an ultra modern browser. Certain features like
> heartbeats, timeouts and disconnection support are vital to realtime
> applications but are not provided by the WebSocket API out of the box.
>
> This is akin to jQuery's decision of creating a feature-rich and
> simple $.ajax API as opposed to normalizing XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding the socket.io client script but forgot to change the code to actually USE it. Using io.connect and socket.on etc works perfect, thanks :)

Comment: alFReD NSH is right, @Martin Hoe you shouldn't use that WS approach anyway since it will only work on a few browsers that have WebSockets native support (for ex on FF that won't work).

Comment: That is the best thing about socket.io, that it is cross-browser, cross-domain, cross-..., Works everywhere. And it is more than WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the webpage source code that runs in Chrome, Firefox, and IE (at least) via the blog article "[Websocket Server Demonstration](http://highlevellogic.blogspot.se/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html)" from the High Level Logic Project. The webpage is set up for developers.